# install apk in background using busybox

Tags: android, busybox, android-install-apk

can i install apk in background using busybox on rooted device ???

i see something like that but it doesn't work

```
process install;
CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "chmod 777 /data/app");
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish(); 
CommandCapture command2 = new CommandCapture(0, "chmod 777 /system/xbin/busybox");
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command2).waitForFinish();
install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/busybox install " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "xxx.apk /data/app/xxx.apk");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `su -c pm install myapp.apk` in a root shell, you should be able install in the background (note the 'pm') part. This has nothing to do with busybox, you can use any shell and you certainly don't need to change permission of `/data/app`.

Comment: thank u for your answer but i want to install apk programmatically not from the shell

Comment: That is exactly what your cod above is trying to do: start a shell (`busybox`) with a command (`install`) and a parameter (`xxx.apk`). The problem is there is no such `install` command, you need to use `pm install`. Where did you copy this code from? Read their docs/readme to understand what it actually does.

Comment: no there is install command in busybox that just copy the apk and put it in the /data/app only and when u restart the device installing start

Comment: Copying do `/data/app` is not the same as installing. Not sure what exactly the busybox command does, but do use the `pm` command if you really want to install it. In any case, what exactly is your problem? How does it 'not work'? Consider revising your original question and providing more details.

Comment: Thank u @Nikolay i got it using pm install

Answer (score 3):

without using busybox

```
install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(install.getOutputStream());  
os.writeBytes("pm install "+APKFile.apk+"\n");  
os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
os.flush();
install.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks you use two paths for your busybox binary. First you `chmod` it in `/system/xbin`, but then you invoke it from `system/bin`. Ensure you use right path. And `chmod 777 /data/app` looks **VERY BAD**.