# Android Install apk silently by busybox command-line

Tags: android, busybox, android-install-apk

I want to install .apk silently in background by BusyBox command. I`ve seen some similar questions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598687/install-apk-in-background-using-busybox), but I still cant get working my code properly...

I have:

1. My .apk I need to install on /sdcard/download/app.apk
2. Root
3. BusyBox installed

Code (not working):

```
String sss = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk";
Process install;
install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/busybox pm install " + sss); 
int success = install.waitFor();
```

If I use "install" instead of "pm install" it copies file well.

P.S. Code above is executing in AsyncTask. No errors, but also nothing happens...
Please help!

Also I tried this, but I`m getting exit value 139 and no result:

```
        Process process;
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        int i = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Apps can't install other apps. You need to execute the install command with root permissions (su). This is already mentioned in the answer of the question you link to tin your question.

Comment: @Robert I just tried to execute su before install: install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); It checks root permission but don`t install .apk

Comment: It works through PC ADB: 1."adb shell"; 2."pm install /mnt/sdcard/download/app.apk". But I can`t repeat it programmatically by executing commands. My Android OS is ICS.

Comment: Your app doesn't get root permission by executing `su`. You have to create a command line that contains su and your command: `su -c 'pm install ...'`

Comment: @Robert I understand that, but I can`t write right commands. Can you help me? I tried this: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); os.writeBytes("pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk\n"); But it doesn`t works.

Comment: I tried also such executing: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk\n" }); but still get EXIT VALUE 139 and the .apk is not installed.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7102780/624109

Comment: Thanks for link, but that`s just the same code. I`ve tried it on two devices: Samsung Galaxy Gio (2.3.7) and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (4.0.3). Gio - everything goes fine, but Tab - nothing happens after executing =( Something bad with ICS... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigations on many android devices I realized that this code is correct and  works!

There was just some problem with one device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 - 4.0.3 ICS). Maybe that is some strange feature of ICS. After updating firmware to 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) problem has been resolved.

Comment: could you please explain which code worked for you? If possible, could you please post working code?

Answer (score 3):

maybe this code will help you

```
Process p = null;
try
{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outs=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

    String cmd="pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk";
    outs.writeBytes(cmd+"\n");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use adb install command to install/update APK silently. Sample code is below

```
public static void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            filename = StringUtil.insertEscape(filename);
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: please, can you post StringUtil.insertEscape(filename) implementation?