# Sliently install .apk programmatically

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

OK,

I know there are are a fair number of questions similar to this, but non have given me the answer I'm looking for.

I have a custom rooted ROM (without play store). It's a android stick pc (So I don't have the system key to sign my app with, unless I've missed something in the kernel docs). I want my app to check nightly for updates from my server. If there is a new version I want it to download and install it without user interaction.

I know I can trigger the update screen with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToApk));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

But as I said it's not what I want. SU and busybox are on the device. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: you should have the system key if you compiled your custom rom. Also, you need to use the PackageManager to install apps, if I recall correctly. You'd need to develop a private api to install your apps, as this is not really supported out of the box.

Comment: It's not a completely custom compile. Since I have to translate alot of the read me and other doc files (as i apear to be missing something since it wont completely compile), I have I just took the original system images and modified them (boot animations, build.props, ect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the PackageManager from the command line using `pm`. If `su` is present, you need to run

```
su pm install pathToApk.apk
```

To run it from a Java application, use `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I tired this, but it didn't install and there was no output. Here is the code that i executed. http://pastebin.com/Bz1EiXQc

Comment: you probably need to read the stderr as well to figure out the reason for the error (call `redirectErrorStream(true)` on your `pb`)

Comment: Also, since this is a shell command, you can also try to run it from an adb shell to test it.

Comment: I got it to work from the adb shell, but still couldn't get it to work through the code. Here is my process that worked through. http://pastebin.com/8LXJ15is

Comment: a few answers on the same topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398543/android-install-apk-silently-by-busybox-command-line

Comment: I changed it to just fire off su and then write the pm command to the process's output stream and that worked.

Comment: @Pyromanci could you post the code that worked. I am struggling with the same problem this very minute.

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have this code (this question was from over a year ago). If you look at njzk2 last comment. The second section of code in the question was basically what I did at the time. Though I no longer do it this way as the App I was doing this with has become a System App in the Custom Rom I was working on and is now updated via OTA updates.